# Counting number of changes between two strings

Tags: c#

String 1:

> So that means his next assignment would be a tour of England in July
>   2016.The remainder of Pakistan's Test specialists will play plenty of limited-overs cricket, including the Asia Cup and the World T20 next
>   year.Misbah who has retired from both the shorter formats.

String 2:

> So that means his next big would be a tour of England in July 2016.The
>   remainder of Pakistan's Test specialists will playing plenty of
>   limited-overs cricket, including in the Asia Cup and the Worlding T20
>   next year.Misbah who has  from both the shorter formats.

in string 2 i have added two words big & in.
modified two word playing(play in string 1) & worlding(world in string 1) and deleted two words(assignment and retired).

so total changes in string 2 is 6 & they are(big,in,playing,worlding,assignment and retired).
but when i counted  get 8 changes.Here is my code.

```
MatchCollection firstText = Regex.Matches(string 1, @"[\S]+");

MatchCollection secondText = Regex.Matches(string 2, @"[\S]+");

var typingText = firstText.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();

var ReviewText = secondText.Cast<Match>().Select(m => m.Value).ToArray();


            List<string> diffe;
            List<string> diffe1;

            IEnumerable<string> str3 = typingText;
            IEnumerable<string> str4 = ReviewText;

            diffe = str4.Except(str3).ToList();    

            diffe1 = str3.Except(str4).ToList();
```

here diffe gives me output 4(two added words & two words modified in string 2)

& diffe1 gives me output 4(two actual deleted word in string 2 & two deleted words(those are modified in string 2))

but i needs to count it 6 as a result.

Comment: This sounds like you want the [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) except instead of comparing characters you're comparing words.

Comment: I've heard cricket is confusing to outsiders, but I've never seen a game.  I have seen descriptions of cricket games, and boy is that confusing.  "Test specialists", "limited-overs", "shorter formats"?  Sorry for the off-topic comment.  This is so alien to me.

Comment: I think part of your problem is that you consider "assignment" being replaced by "big" as 2 changes, but "play" replaced by "playing" as only 1 change.  What exactly determines when a replacement should count as 1 or 2 changes?  I get that "play" is a substring of "playing", but you need to determine exactly how to differentiate.